# WPF, TextBox.Text bind to TimeSpan type property

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, mask, timespan

There is TextBox.Text, which binded to Nullable TimeSpan property. When trying type value to TextBox text input occurs unpredictably.

Code:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="120" Margin="60,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ForCv,Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         Text="{Binding Path=TimeFrom, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I want to type on mask "00:00:00" but I don`t know how it might work. Mask for this TextBox not defined, it defineds somewhere inside binding or TimeSpan type (for example according ToString() return value method). Please, help.

P.S. Sorry for my eng.

Comment: check [`MaskedTextBox`](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Home) of Extended WPF Toolkit

Comment: MaskedTextBox perfectly resolve the problem. But there is new problem: after add xctk:MaskedTextBox designer says: "The type 'xctk:MaskedTextBox' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built." Reference to Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit exists and xmnls has added to xaml. Assembly succesfully build and control work but designer don`t shows.

Comment: check [this](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/267757) link. It might help you

Comment: Problem successfully resolved. Thank you, dkozl.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the StringFormat-property inside the binding.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeFrom, StringFormat=hh\\:mm\\:ss}" ...></TextBlock>
```

Edit:

For textboxes [this link](http://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/wpf-masked-textbox-behavior/) may help you.

Comment: Thank you, Sukram. But typing still unpredictably. Probably need coding class, which derives from TextBox and look to typed value in TextChanged handler. I don`t see another way resolve this question.

Comment: Sorry did not notice that you used a textbox.

I add a link maybe that will help you.